# Why $V^{\pi^*}(s) = \max_{a \in A}Q^{\pi^*}(s,a),\forall s \in S$ in reinforcement learning?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

When i read some notes about RL i encounterd following equation and try to prove it:
$$
V^{\pi^*}(s) = \max_{a \in A}Q^{\pi^*}(s, a),\forall s \in S
$$

Here is my attemption:
Firstly, i only need to prove "$\geq$" as "$\leq$" is obvious.

Soppose that $\exists S_0 \subset S$ such that $\forall s_0 \in S_0,V^{\pi^*}(s_0) < \max_{a \in A}Q^{\pi^*}(s_0, a)$.(W.L.G, soppose there is only single state $s_0 \in S_0$), i want to construct a new policy $\pi_{\text{new}}$ to derive the contradiction to $V^{\pi^*}(s) \geq V^{\pi}(s), \forall s \in S$ and all policy $\pi$.

I try to create the following policy:
$$\pi_{\text{new}}(a\vert s)=\begin{cases}
1& s=s_0,a=\text{argmax}_{a\in A}Q^{\pi^*}(s_0,a)\\
0& s=s_0, a\neq \text{argmax}_{a\in A}Q^{\pi^*}(s_0,a) \\
\pi^*(a\vert s)& s \in S - s_0
\end{cases}
$$

Next I want to show
$$
V^{\pi_{\text{new}}}(s_0) = \max_{a\in A}Q^{\pi^*}(s_0, a)
$$
And thus $V^{\pi_{\text{new}}}(s_0) > V^{\pi^*}(s_0)$ to get contradiction. But I encounted some trouble as follow when derived it.
$$
V^{\pi_{\text{new}}}(s_0) = \sum_{a \in A}\pi_{\text{new}}(a \vert s_0)Q^{\pi_{\text{new}}}(s_0, a) = Q^{\pi_{\text{new}}}(s_0, \text{argmax}_{a\in A}Q^{\pi^*}(s_0, a)) \overset{?}{=} \max_{a \in A}Q^{\pi^*}(s_0, a)
$$

I guess the last equation is hold but i can't find a way to prove it. Because policy changed.

Please give me some methods to state it. Thanks advanced for your help!